Tag usage clarification discussion for [programming-interface]
I recently edited a question, and changed the [cryptoapi] tag to [programming-interface]. An awkward situation is that, the usage of [cryptoapi] is specific but narrow; and [programming-interface] tag is lacking a description and a usage guide.
There's a few questions currently tagged [programming-interface], usages vary. This Q seeks to clarify the usage of the [programming-interface] tag, edit the existing questions as appropriate, and (if orthodox in StackExchange practice) create and add other more appropriate tags for questions that doesn't fit (the new) usage guide for [programming-interface].
